# Override User-Agent to static value on Apache Server regardless of what client sends

Tags: apache

Notwithstanding the wisdom of doing such a thing, is it possible to have Apache override the User-Agent to a static string regardless of what the client sends over in the request?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader

Comment: @CBRoe: You should make that an answer.

Comment: @CBroe, I second Andrew's comment. I know it's short but it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate incoming request headers using the [RequestHeader](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive:

> *“This directive can replace, merge, change or remove HTTP request headers. The header is modified just before the content handler is run, allowing incoming headers to be modified.”*